# Remove string literal '\n' and replace with a newline

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like,

```
var testNote = "Test\r\nMulti \r\nLinme\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLineeeeeeeeee\r\n"
```

But I want it to display like,

```
Test
Multi 
Linme



Lineeeeeeeeee
```

Comment: Where, in HTML? Replace it with <br>.

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

`testNote = testNote.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")` and so on.

```js
var testNote = "Test\r\nMulti \r\nLinme\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLineeeeeeeeee\r\n"
console.log(testNote.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br/>"));
```

Comment: You mean `testNote = testNote.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br/>")`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript supports all the escape characters you have in your string.  But that doesn't mean that you'll necessarily see them in the output.

Take a look at this example, which uses a `<pre>` tag in html to preserve these whitespace characters.

```html
<pre id='p'></pre>
<script>
  var testNote = "Test\r\nMulti \r\nLinme\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLineeeeeeeeee\r\n"
  document.getElementById('p').textContent = testNote;
 </script>
```